# Android Studio 2.1.2: Can't install on Windows 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

During install, I keep getting the following error:

```
Old dir was moved away, but new one failed to be moved into place. 
Trying to move old one back.java.io.IOException: failed to move
 new dir into place Warning: An error occurred during installation: 
failed to move new dir into place.
```

During installation, I get a pop-up that reads: "he following SDK component was not installed: Android SDK Platform-Tools 24.0.1".

I click "OK" (the choice is between "ok" and "cancel"), and the stupid thing just stops installing the IDE!

I've maybe reinstalled this infernal thing 20 times now, and to no avail.  Before each reinstall, I would uninstall and remove all the files and folders the poorly written and cruddy uninstaller didn't remove, and then I installed again.

I've tried running the installer as admin, running Android Studio as admin during the time it downloads and installs all this crap (which is when the error occurs), I've tried leaving "install Android SDK Platform-Tool 24.0.1" unchecked at the beginning....  I've tried everything I possibly can...  and I've spent hours on this trying to get the bloody thing to just [curse] install... it shouldn't be this hard!

**Is there anyone who has come accross this and fixed it?  I need to get this installed and working.**

Also, I'd appreciate a source for downloading previous versions, as the stupid site doesn't provide one for **absurd** reasons only the google devs would know.

**Update**:  Aparently Android Studio works, but when I try to update the SDK using the SDK manager as administrator, I get the following:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24.0.1
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24.0.1
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Unzip failed: C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe (Access is denied)
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

And I need to be able to update the platform tools to 24 to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what was happening, and this isn't an obvious solution.

My AntiVirus identified adb.exe as a threat, and removed it.  Afterwards, it prevented the file from being created again, and that's where the error was coming from.